# is it possible to communicate through socket with django

Tags: python, django, sockets

Hello i have a server program in python

built with  `socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)`

I have to make a web application for the users.
the web application must send a string to the server.
my question is :
Can i use django to build a web application, and send a string to the python server ?
thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the clients will be communicating with Django server via TCP connection by WSGI protocol and some server-side code will be establishing UDP-connection with your Python server.

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "127.0.0.1"
UDP_PORT = 5005

# django view
def send_string_to_udp_server_view(request):
    message = request.GET.get('message')  # message presumably sent as query string
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    sock.sendto(message, (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    sock.close()
```

**PS:** for simplicity sake the code lacks all the checks and exceptions handling.

Comment: Thank you mate , i was just wondering if the python Socket structure and Socket method where accessible in django
You answered perfectly :)